# ¿como soluciono problema de autenticacion de sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de loguearme con sql server al servidor, ya tengo el usuario creado, tengo habilitada las conexiones remotas, tambien "Name pipes", y sin embargo no loguea el sistema.
Si me funciona la autenticación por windows, pero la necesito por sql server
[image: Error al autenticar por sql server]

[image: Propiedades de mi conexión]

[image: Propiedades del servidor]

[image: Propiedades del servidor Security]

[image: Allow remote connections]

[image: Usuarios]

[image: login prop]

[image: server role]

[image: user mapping]

[image: securables]

[image: status]

Comment: El error que muestras no es de autenticación sino de conexión. No se encuentra la instancia a la cual te deseas conectar. Revisa que el cliente tenga acceso a la red y que el nombre esté correctamente escrito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error que te da es que no puede encontrar el servidor. 
Viendo que se trata de la versión `Express`, lo más probable es que te falte algo por configurar.

Primero tienes que ir a `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, `SQL Server Configuration`, `Protocols` y activar `TCP/IP`.

Luego en la rama de `SQL Native Client`, `Configuration`, `Client Protocols`, abres `TCP/IP` y en `Default Port` pones 1433 (probablemente lo tendrás vacío).

Para asegurarte, reinicias el servicio de `SQL Server` y podrás acceder desde la red. Aunque puede que debas abrir el puerto 1433 en el `firewall` de `Windows`.

Comment: Se soluciono habilitando el puerto en el firewall. gracias